# How to start lazy init on worker thread

Tags: kotlin

I have a field `val mThing` that I init with `by lazyThing()`. Now I expect the `lazyThing()` call to take a moment, so I would like to start the initialization on a worker thread. Obviously it is fine if some other thread comes along and needs `mThing` and waits for it, but I would like to start the initialization as soon as possible on a worker thread. Whats a good looking way of doing this in Kotlin?

Or if there is a better pattern than lazy initialization I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Why is the worker thread needed? If you don't care if a thread blocks while initialising, then I guess as long as the initialisation is synchronous you can just simply run `lazyThing()` and let the thread block. I don't know the use case, but this is usually quite dangerous in for example Android applications, where you may accidentally block the UI thread, which cannot be blocked. In other scenarios, this might be totally fine.

Comment: @Fred worker thread is needed for that exact reason. theoretically somewhere down the line if something UI dependent needs this object then of course we will have to wait (we won't block the UI thread but we may need to show a spinner in the meantime), so it would be nice to spin up the initialization on a worker thread. we can accomplish this in various ways but i would like to see some clean ones

Comment: Then I would say lazy initialization with kotlin delegates doesn't seem to fit. These will block the thread until the result is available. The semantics also call for such behavior, since once you read a variable you expect the result to be read synchronously. The fact that it's lazily initialize I suppose it's an internal detail. It would be weird to read a variable and not block until it's ready to use. What interim value would you return? In this situation I'd expose a worker or something that the caller knows will run asynchronous - like rxjava observables usually do.

Answer (score 1):

You may specify synchronization mode in the `lazy` function: 
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-lazy-thread-safety-mode/index.html

The simplest way cloud be to let JVM do the initialization on class load. So you may declare a class or object that has the field with the computation results. Next, the JVM will do the necessary locks:

```
object ComputeValueOnClassLoad {
  val value = lazyThing()
}
```

The first worker thread will use the class, it will initialize the class loading and thus compute the value. Other threads will wait for it